# Running all test with PHPUnit in Symfony

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit 5.4.8 and Symfony 2.3

I have all my bundles with unit tests and I would like to run all those tests, with coverage in html. I tried with the command

```
phpunit -c app --no-globals-backup --coverage-html ~/coverage/ src/*Bundles/Tests/Unit
```

But it just doesn't work.

This is my test suite in phpunit.xml.dist

```
<testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
 </testsuites>
```

Comment: `But it just doesn't work.` Can you be more specific?

Comment: It throws the error: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Mockery_57f53d6f8d9b8'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to do it, first the name of the test suite can't have blank spaces, so phpunit.xml.dist file is this now:

```
<testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
 </testsuites>
```

And you run the test suite with command:

```
phpunit -c app --no-globals-backup --coverage-html ~/coverage/ --testsuite Project
```